# How to use Topological Sorting result to resolve dependencies to generate final object code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, topological-sort

Below I am attaching a simple dependency list as an example.  I am  using Unix tsort to solve the same by numbering the nodes

[image]

```
Root 0
File1 1
File2 2
File1.cpp 3
File2.cpp 4

> tsort 
 0 1
 0 2
 1 3
 2 4

 Generates:
 0 2 1 3 4
```

What I fail to comprehend is to how to use this dependency list efficiently in order to recompile only the changed files ?
I am just trying to understand how does make internally work and attempting to build my own little prototype for the same.
Any other approach apart from topological sorting is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, make probably doesn't really use topological ordering anymore: naively generating a linear list of work items this way doesn't lend itself to parallelism.

I don't know what make actually does, but the idea is to first prune the dependency tree (remove leaves whose dependencies are unchanged, which may create new leaves, so repeat until nothing gets removed anymore), and then do a parallel depth-first visitation to build each node.

Comment: In my example, none of the leaves can be removed. So how do I implement parallel depth-first visitation to build ?